# Android studio 1.5 unable to get the emulator running?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android 1.5.  I'm facing an issue while trying to run Android emulator.  It doesn't initialize properly and keeps failing with the below exceptions.
Emulator config : Nexus S API 23.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Exception log:

```
02-07 06:36:48.381 3893-3893/system_process E/System: ******************************************
02-07 06:36:48.403 3893-3893/system_process E/System: ************ Failure starting system services
                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: There must be one required installer
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getRequiredInstallerLPr(PackageManagerService.java:2421)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:2327)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:1764)
at com.android.server.SystemServer.startBootstrapServices(SystemServer.java:366)
at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:268)
at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:168)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-07 06:36:48.407 3893-3893/system_process D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-07 06:36:48.411 3893-3893/system_process E/AndroidRuntime: *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: There must be one required installer
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getRequiredInstallerLPr(PackageManagerService.java:2421)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:2327)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:1764)
at com.android.server.SystemServer.startBootstrapServices(SystemServer.java:366)
at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:268)
at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:168)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-07 06:36:48.461 3893-3893/system_process E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.IActivityManager.handleApplicationCrash(android.os.IBinder, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo)' on a null object reference
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
02-07 06:36:48.462 3893-3893/system_process I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3893 SIG: 9
02-07 06:36:49.312 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'batterystats' died
02-07 06:36:49.312 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'appops' died
02-07 06:36:49.312 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'power' died
02-07 06:36:49.312 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'display' died
02-07 06:36:49.406 967-967/? E/installd: eof
02-07 06:36:49.407 967-967/? E/installd: failed to read size
02-07 06:36:49.407 967-967/? I/installd: closing connection
02-07 06:36:49.542 3785-3785/? E/Zygote: Exit zygote because system server (3893) has terminated
```

Comment: try it with other api images also. Api 23 is quite buggy still

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the packages installed? It doesn't look like. Go to SDK manager and check what hasn't been downloaded

Comment: Except for something called "Glass development kit", all the packages are installed .... still getting this error :(

Comment: create a new avd with lower API